# TypeError: 'PasswordField' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, authentication, sqlite3-python

I am working on a user authentication system allowing users login with password and email. But I keep getting error 500. I checked and saw this error (this is only part of the error):

```
2023-05-12 10:53:09,480 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine \[generated in 0.00102s\] ('user@user.com', 1, 0)
\[2023-05-12 10:53:09,483\] ERROR in app: Exception on /login \[POST\]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\\mercy\\TSP\\Dam-1\\app.py", line 32, in login
if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\mercy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\flask_bcrypt.py", line 225, in check_password_hash
return hmac.compare_digest(bcrypt.hashpw(password, pw_hash), pw_hash)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\\mercy\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\bcrypt\__init_\_.py", line 82, in hashpw
password = password\[:72\]
\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~^^^^^
TypeError: 'PasswordField' object is not subscriptable
```

This is the code I used:

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = local_session.query(User).filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user:
            if bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password):
                login_user(user)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard.html'), email=form.email.data)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = EmailField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=30)], render_kw={'placeholder': 'email'})
    password = PasswordField(validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=20)], render_kw={'placeholder': 'password'})
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

I was expecting it to return the dashboard page with this line:

```
<body>
    <h1>welcome {{% email %}}</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: what is `FlaskForm` ?  where is it defined ?